# SQL statement inserts 2 rows instead of 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.configuration_parameter
(
  id SERIAL,
  type parameter_type NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT configuration_parameter_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.parameter_varchar
(
-- Inherited from table configuration_parameter:  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('configuration_parameter_id_seq'::regclass),
-- Inherited from table configuration_parameter:  type parameter_type NOT NULL,
  configuration_parameter_id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying NOT NULL,
  is_required boolean NOT NULL,
  default_value character varying,
  max_length integer,
  CONSTRAINT parameter_varchar_pk PRIMARY KEY (configuration_parameter_id),
  CONSTRAINT configuration_parameter_varchar_fk FOREIGN KEY (configuration_parameter_id)
      REFERENCES public.configuration_parameter (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
INHERITS (public.configuration_parameter);
```

As you can see, parameter_varchar inherits from configuration_parameter. 
The ID's of all parameters are stored in configuration_parameter, as to avoid double parameter ID's. I want to be able to have a list of parameters (the ones in the parent, configuration_parameter) which are further specified in one of the children like parameter_varchar (or the other children parameter_integer and some others).

Now I want to add a parameter. My thought was to first add a row to the parent table (configuration_parameter), and then a row into the child (parameter_varchar) to further specify the parameter. The configuration_parameter_ID needs to be the same as the one of the row added to configuration_parameter.

This is the statement I use:

```
with inserted as (
INSERT INTO configuration_parameter(type)
VALUES ('varchar') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO parameter_varchar(type, configuration_parameter_id, name, is_required, max_length)
select 'varchar', inserted.id, 'APN Name', 'false', 32 from inserted;
```

What happens now is, there is one row in parameter_varchar with all the things I specified, with id=12 and configuration_parameter_id=11.
But in configuration_parameter there are 2 rows added with id=11 and id=12. configuration_parameter with id=12 shouldn't be there.

Either my statement is wrong, or I understood some principle of inheritance wrong and made a mistake in the DB itself.
Can someone please explain what I did wrong and why it went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is wrong if you only want to insert one row.

When one table inherits from another, then it inherits the columns.  You don't put rows into separate tables.  So, you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO parameter_varchar(type, name, is_required, max_length)
    SELECT 'varchar', 'APN Name', 'false', 32 ;
```

The `id` column is inherited, so `parameter_varchar` "knows" that it is a serial column.

Comment: That throws an error: ERROR:  null value in column "configuration_parameter_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: @Kailayla that answer is a bit short. your ddl is wrong. you either inherit or relate (foreign key). you can't do both. i suggest you drop the inheritance. read futher  [docs] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)

Comment: @Aツ He can do both. It is not that it is wrong but that in his case it makes no sense.

Comment: @Aツ Thanks. I read it and I removed the inheritance as that indeed is not the behavior I wanted.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto You are right, it indeed made no sense. I had a gut feeling it wasn't the way to go with what I wanted to do, but stubborn as I am I did it anyway. So thank you too. (and btw, I'm a she ;) It's alright though, you couldn't have known).

Answer (score 0):

[From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

> Use of INHERITS creates a persistent relationship between the new child table and its parent table(s). Schema modifications to the parent(s) normally propagate to children as well, and **by default the data of the child table is included in scans of the parent(s)**

Emphasis mine. If you do not want that behavior then use `like` in instead of `inherits` or use `only` in the select command:

```
select * 
from only configuration_parameter
```

But if there is a foreign key to the parent then you do not need inheritance.